# jnlp Extended key usage does not permit use for code signing

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, keytool, jarsigner

I have a situation where launching a JNLP generates the message:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Extended key usage does not permit use for code signing.

Here is the catch:
The problem only happens if I generate the private key and csr with java's keytool, send the csr to be signed (without code_sign extension), then import the signed certificate along with intermediate and root ca into the originally created private key's keystore. Once this is done I create a jar with the public key (and tried it with importing intermediate and root ca's) and sign it with the keystore that has everything.

Some of you might be thinking to yourself that there is no catch and that this sounds correct. So maybe this is the catch... the problem doesn't happen if I generate the private key and csr with openssl. Once I do this I get back the signed cert (also without code_sign extension) and create a p12 that I use to create the java keystore using:
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore combinedpubandpriv.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore newkeystore.jks -deststoretype JKS

Once the keystore is created this way I add the intermediate and root ca to it, create the jar and sign it without eventually getting the "Extended key usage does not permit use for code signing".

So the question is somewhat twofold. 
1. Why does the jar signed after creating private and csr via openssl not get this error; and
2. Is there anyway to not get the error when creating the private and csr via java's keytool command?

10/21 UPDATE:
I can't reproduce anymore. But these were the openssl commands that I had been using when I was able to sign the jar with the openssl generated certificates:

[10/24: Steps removed since they were not an accurate representation of how I was able to get it working]

---

10/24 EDIT:

I can reproduce this again. Here are the details.

I have come to the conclusion that java is either:

  1. interpreting the openssl generated certs as a self-signed certificate (because it doesn't have a certificate chain); or

  2. is unable to run jnlp's signed with certificates that has a certificate chain greater than 1 without the code signing EKU.

Using these steps **I DO NOT get the error** mentioned in the title:

  1. openssl genrsa -aes256 -out /home/user/ca/intermediate/private/myserver.key.pem -passout pass:password 2048

  2. openssl req -days 365 -config /home/user/ca/intermediate/openssl.cnf -out /home/user/ca/intermediate/csr/myserver.csr -key /home/user/ca/intermediate/private/myserver.key.pem -new -passin pass:password

  3. openssl ca -config /home/user/ca/intermediate/openssl.cnf -extensions server_cert -days 365 -notext -md sha256 -out /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/myserver.cert.pem -infiles /home/user/ca/intermediate/csr/myserver.csr

  4. openssl pkcs12 -export -in /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/myserver.cert.pem -inkey /home/user/ca/intermediate/private/myserver.key.pem -out /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/myserver.p12 -name testalias -password pass:password -passin pass:password

  5. keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/myserver.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore custom.jks -deststoretype JKS -srcstorepass password -deststorepass password

  6. keytool -importcert -alias rootca -file /home/user/ca/certs/ca.cert.pem -keystore custom.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

  7. keytool -importcert -alias intermediateca -file /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem -keystore custom.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

  8. keytool -exportcert -alias testalias -file export.crt -keystore custom.jks -storepass password

  9. keytool -importcert -alias testalias -file export.crt -keystore testabc.jks -storepass password -v -rfc

  10. jar cvf custom.jar testabc.jks

  11. jarsigner -keystore ./custom.jks -verbose -keypass password -storepass password custom.jar testalias

**NOTES:**

  1: The jar file I created does need to be named custom.jar. If it isn't then it generates an error "JAR resources in JNLP file are not signed by same certificate".

  2: I created a root and intermediate signing ca using the steps here: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/ (Thanks Jamie!)

  3: My openssl.cnf is a subset of: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/_downloads/intermediate-config.txt

  4: My openssl.cnf differs from that linked in NOTE3 in that:

    a. dir points to different directory

    b. I removed policy_strict, v3_intermediate_ca, usr_cert crl_ext, and ocsp sections

    c. Changed defaults in the req_distinguished name section.

    d. removed critical from v3_ca basicConstraints and keyUsage section - though the problem was present before this.

    e. removed crtical from server_cert keyUsage section

Using these steps **I DO get the error** mentioned in the title:

  1. keytool -genkeypair -keystore custom.jks -storepass password -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keypass password -alias testalias

  2. keytool -certreq -keystore custom.jks -storepass password -alias testalias -keypass password -file myserver.csr

  3. openssl ca -config /home/user/ca/intermediate/openssl.cnf.BeforeModifyingForCSRs -extensions server_cert -days 365 -notext -md sha256 -out /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/myserver.cert.pem -infiles myserver.csr

  4. keytool -importcert -alias rootca -file /home/user/ca/certs/ca.cert.pem -keystore custom.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

  5. keytool -importcert -alias intermediateca -file /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem -keystore custom.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

  6. keytool -importcert -alias testalias -file /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/myserver.cert.pem -keystore custom.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

  7. keytool -exportcert -alias testalias -file export.crt -keystore custom.jks -storepass password

  8. keytool -importcert -alias testalias -file export.crt -keystore testabc.jks -storepass password -v -rfc

  9. jar cvf custom.jar testabc.jks

  10. jarsigner -keystore ./custom.jks -verbose -keypass password -storepass password custom.jar testalias

keytool output of keystore and alias **with problem**:

```
Enter keystore password:  
Alias name: testalias  
Creation date: Oct 12, 2016  
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry  
Certificate chain length: 3  
Certificate[1]:  
Owner: CN=myserver, OU=CA, O=CA, L=CA, ST=CA, C=CA  
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=intermediateca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US  
Serial number: 1044  
Valid from: Wed Oct 12 12:16:00 EDT 2016 until: Thu Oct 12 12:16:00 EDT 2017  
Certificate fingerprints:  
        MD5:  EE:26:A8:D3:6A:21:27:01:F1:98:A2:12:91:CB:7D:FE  
        SHA1: E0:2E:A1:38:DE:A6:C8:53:AF:C2:A1:25:73:F3:AB:3A:A7:19:ED:6C  
        SHA256: A4:12:4A:7A:65:A5:A7:42:36:DC:86:54:D8:6C:50:42:9B:45:40:6F:C3:99:F9:64:D8:DA:F7:B3:B2:2A:DD:0E  
        Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA  
        Version: 3  

Extensions:  
#1: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13 Criticality=false  
0000: 16 24 4F 70 65 6E 53 53   4C 20 47 65 6E 65 72 61  .$OpenSSL Genera  
0010: 74 65 64 20 53 65 72 76   65 72 20 43 65 72 74 69  ted Server Certi  
0020: 66 69 63 61 74 65                                  ficate  


#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false  
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [  
KeyIdentifier [  
0000: EA 08 F0 F6 CC 10 32 7B   A9 A1 93 7A A3 82 A0 11  ......2....z....  
0010: AC 13 03 D2                                        ....  
]  
[EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=rootca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US]  
SerialNumber: [    1000]  
]  

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false  
BasicConstraints:[  
  CA:false  
  PathLen: undefined  
]  

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false  
ExtendedKeyUsages [  
  serverAuth  
]  

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true  
KeyUsage [  
  DigitalSignature  
  Key_Encipherment  
]  

#6: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false  
NetscapeCertType [  
   SSL server  
]  

#7: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false  
SubjectKeyIdentifier [  
KeyIdentifier [  
0000: 8E 89 8C 3A 9C 41 B3 9E   F6 A8 C1 F6 DD 30 9B 12  ...:.A.......0..  
0010: FA 0C 29 90                                        ..).  
]  
]  

Certificate[2]:  
Owner: EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=intermediateca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US  
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=rootca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US  
Serial number: 1000  
Valid from: Thu Mar 17 15:44:38 EDT 2016 until: Sun Mar 15 15:44:38 EDT 2026  
Certificate fingerprints:  
         MD5:  E8:B8:A9:F9:57:99:CB:AD:EC:33:D7:93:41:3C:BF:C5  
         SHA1: BA:E4:7A:3C:F9:3C:40:4A:ED:31:69:84:F1:FC:48:BF:A2:46:C6:64  
         SHA256: A4:79:DB:0E:34:CE:EE:32:AC:4D:59:96:97:22:7F:EA:D3:B5:54:9E:07:AF:DB:5D:FE:C4:7F:C0:2A:10:3B:AA  
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA  
         Version: 3  

Extensions:   

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false  
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [  
KeyIdentifier [  
0000: BE 53 42 23 BD 7C 92 61   20 DF 9D 6A CE EA 90 85  .SB#...a ..j....  
0010: 6D 46 60 02                                        mF`.  
]  
]  

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true  
BasicConstraints:[  
  CA:true  
  PathLen:0  
]  

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true  
KeyUsage [  
  DigitalSignature  
  Key_CertSign  
  Crl_Sign  
]  

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false  
SubjectKeyIdentifier [  
KeyIdentifier [  
0000: EA 08 F0 F6 CC 10 32 7B   A9 A1 93 7A A3 82 A0 11  ......2....z....  
0010: AC 13 03 D2                                        ....  
]  
]  

Certificate[3]:  
Owner: EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=rootca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US  
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=rootca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US  
Serial number: cd02b56d83aaa294  
Valid from: Thu Mar 17 15:43:27 EDT 2016 until: Wed Mar 12 15:43:27 EDT 2036  
Certificate fingerprints:  
         MD5:  02:FD:FC:8A:C9:BC:0C:DE:0F:E2:41:D7:7A:7D:BE:78  
         SHA1: EC:F0:F5:C4:24:0A:E0:C1:4F:2F:C0:82:20:09:86:31:4D:7A:D3:A2  
         SHA256: 0E:3B:64:DA:11:A7:D9:43:3A:01:01:79:C4:5F:12:DF:9A:87:85:10:37:6D:B9:CF:DB:EE:7B:57:5F:50:E8:E0  
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA  
         Version: 3  

Extensions:   

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false  
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [  
KeyIdentifier [  
0000: BE 53 42 23 BD 7C 92 61   20 DF 9D 6A CE EA 90 85  .SB#...a ..j....  
0010: 6D 46 60 02                                        mF`.  
]  
]  

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true  
BasicConstraints:[  
  CA:true  
  PathLen:2147483647  
]  

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true  
KeyUsage [  
  DigitalSignature  
  Key_CertSign  
  Crl_Sign  
]  

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false  
SubjectKeyIdentifier [  
KeyIdentifier [  
0000: BE 53 42 23 BD 7C 92 61   20 DF 9D 6A CE EA 90 85  .SB#...a ..j....  
0010: 6D 46 60 02                                        mF`.  
]  
]
```

keytool output of keystore and alias **without problem**:

```
Enter keystore password:  
Alias name: testalias
Creation date: Oct 12, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: EMAILADDRESS=myuser@myorg.com, CN=myserver, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=intermediateca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US
Serial number: 1042
Valid from: Wed Oct 12 10:57:01 EDT 2016 until: Thu Oct 12 10:57:01 EDT 2017
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  40:D0:69:90:87:41:88:33:92:EE:4F:E7:74:1F:F2:C8
         SHA1: 41:BC:5F:14:D1:89:40:3E:BA:B8:CF:D0:07:1A:74:54:EB:C0:8C:F4
         SHA256: F8:4F:74:B6:CD:2B:12:52:0C:78:96:A8:18:90:11:30:9D:E5:10:6B:FE:F8:7A:B9:A4:E5:9E:20:BF:E2:A7:A2
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13 Criticality=false
0000: 16 24 4F 70 65 6E 53 53   4C 20 47 65 6E 65 72 61  .$OpenSSL Genera
0010: 74 65 64 20 53 65 72 76   65 72 20 43 65 72 74 69  ted Server Certi
0020: 66 69 63 61 74 65                                  ficate


#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: EA 08 F0 F6 CC 10 32 7B   A9 A1 93 7A A3 82 A0 11  ......2....z....
0010: AC 13 03 D2                                        ....
]
[EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=rootca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US]
SerialNumber: [    1000]
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

#6: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
NetscapeCertType [
   SSL server
]

#7: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: C3 3A D6 16 1D 2F D4 B9   2E FD E7 8E 97 32 D3 0A  .:.../.......2..
0010: 5B 13 4E B7                                        [.N.
]
]
```

jarsigner -verify output of jar file **without problem**:
jarsigner -verify -verbose -keystore custom.jks -certs custom.jar testalias

```
s k      151 Wed Oct 12 12:48:00 EDT 2016 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=myuser@myorg.com, CN=myserver, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US (testalias)
      [certificate is valid from 10/12/16 12:47 PM to 10/12/17 12:47 PM]
      [ExtendedKeyUsage, NetscapeCertType extension does not support code signing]

         313 Wed Oct 12 12:48:00 EDT 2016 META-INF/TESTALIA.SF
        1972 Wed Oct 12 12:48:00 EDT 2016 META-INF/TESTALIA.RSA
           0 Wed Oct 12 12:48:00 EDT 2016 META-INF/
smk     1545 Wed Oct 12 12:48:00 EDT 2016 testabc.jks

      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=myuser@myorg.com, CN=myserver, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US (testalias)
      [certificate is valid from 10/12/16 12:47 PM to 10/12/17 12:47 PM]
      [ExtendedKeyUsage, NetscapeCertType extension does not support code signing]


  s = signature was verified 
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope
  X = not signed by specified alias(es)

jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate's ExtendedKeyUsage extension doesn't allow code signing.
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate's NetscapeCertType extension doesn't allow code signing.
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2017-10-12) or after any future revocation date.
```

jarsigner -verify output of jar file **with problem**:
jarsigner -verify -verbose -keystore custom.jks -certs custom.jar testalias

```
s k      151 Wed Oct 12 12:16:36 EDT 2016 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

      X.509, CN=myserver, OU=CA, O=CA, L=CA, ST=CA, C=CA (testalias)
      [certificate is valid from 10/12/16 12:16 PM to 10/12/17 12:16 PM]
      [ExtendedKeyUsage, NetscapeCertType extension does not support code signing]
      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=intermediateca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US (intermediateca)
      [certificate is valid from 3/17/16 3:44 PM to 3/15/26 3:44 PM]
      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=rootca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US (rootca)
      [certificate is valid from 3/17/16 3:43 PM to 3/12/36 3:43 PM]

         313 Wed Oct 12 12:16:36 EDT 2016 META-INF/TESTALIA.SF
        4976 Wed Oct 12 12:16:36 EDT 2016 META-INF/TESTALIA.RSA
           0 Wed Oct 12 12:16:36 EDT 2016 META-INF/
smk     1509 Wed Oct 12 12:16:36 EDT 2016 testabc.jks

      X.509, CN=myserver, OU=CA, O=CA, L=CA, ST=CA, C=CA (testalias)
      [certificate is valid from 10/12/16 12:16 PM to 10/12/17 12:16 PM]
      [ExtendedKeyUsage, NetscapeCertType extension does not support code signing]
      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=intermediateca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US (intermediateca)
      [certificate is valid from 3/17/16 3:44 PM to 3/15/26 3:44 PM]
      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=rootca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US (rootca)
      [certificate is valid from 3/17/16 3:43 PM to 3/12/36 3:43 PM]


  s = signature was verified 
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope
  X = not signed by specified alias(es)

jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate's ExtendedKeyUsage extension doesn't allow code signing.
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate's NetscapeCertType extension doesn't allow code signing.
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2017-10-12) or after any future revocation date.
```

The way I have come to the 2 conclusions above is based on following a slightly modified set of the problematic steps that allow the jnlp without the error. Here are those steps:

  1. keytool -genkeypair -keystore custom.jks -storepass password -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keypass password -alias testalias

  2. keytool -certreq -keystore custom.jks -storepass password -alias testalias -keypass password -file myserver.csr

  3. openssl ca -config /home/user/ca/intermediate/openssl.cnf -extensions server_cert -days 365 -notext -md sha256 -out /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/myserver.cert.pem -infiles myserver.csr

  4. keytool -importcert -alias rootca -file /home/user/ca/certs/ca.cert.pem -keystore custom.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

  5. keytool -importcert -alias intermediateca -file /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem -keystore custom.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

  6. keytool -importcert -alias testalias -file /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/myserver.cert.pem -keystore custom.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

** deviate begin **

  7. keytool -importkeystore -alias testalias -srckeystore custom.jks -destkeystore custom.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass password -deststorepass password -srcalias testalias -destalias testalias

  8. openssl pkcs12 -in custom.p12 -out custom.pem -nodes -password pass:password

  9. manually remove the certificates for rootca and intermediateca

  10. openssl pkcs12 -export -in custom.pem -inkey custom.pem -out custom2.p12 -name testalias -password pass:password -passin pass:password

  11. keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore custom2.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore custom2.jks -deststoretype JKS -srcstorepass password -deststorepass password

  12. keytool -importcert -alias rootca -file /home/user/ca/certs/ca.cert.pem -keystore custom2.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

  13. keytool -importcert -alias intermediateca -file /home/user/ca/intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem -keystore custom2.jks -v -rfc -storepass password

** deviate end **

  14. keytool -exportcert -alias testalias -file export.crt -keystore custom2.jks -storepass password

  15. keytool -importcert -alias testalias -file export.crt -keystore testabc.jks -storepass password -v -rfc

  16. jar cvf custom.jar testabc.jks

  17. jarsigner -keystore ./custom2.jks -verbose -keypass password -storepass password custom.jar testalias

keytool -list output of this this recent custom2.jks file **without problem**:
keytool -list -v -alias testalias -keystore custom2.jks

```
Enter keystore password:  
Alias name: testalias
Creation date: Oct 12, 2016
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=myserver, OU=CA, O=CA, L=CA, ST=CA, C=CA
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=intermediateca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US
Serial number: 1047
Valid from: Wed Oct 12 14:33:32 EDT 2016 until: Thu Oct 12 14:33:32 EDT 2017
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  00:88:00:E1:E4:C2:32:67:A2:0B:20:6E:1D:B8:60:FF
         SHA1: 4A:A4:05:CE:56:8C:32:48:AC:0B:1C:72:29:D7:28:F4:1C:C7:87:DA
         SHA256: 80:6A:35:52:8D:EC:90:FD:6F:42:02:8C:02:4D:85:C7:EE:FD:E1:47:64:CE:D4:4B:7E:F7:9F:8B:68:68:0D:21
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13 Criticality=false
0000: 16 24 4F 70 65 6E 53 53   4C 20 47 65 6E 65 72 61  .$OpenSSL Genera
0010: 74 65 64 20 53 65 72 76   65 72 20 43 65 72 74 69  ted Server Certi
0020: 66 69 63 61 74 65                                  ficate


#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: EA 08 F0 F6 CC 10 32 7B   A9 A1 93 7A A3 82 A0 11  ......2....z....
0010: AC 13 03 D2                                        ....
]
[EMAILADDRESS=mycertadmin@myorg.com, CN=rootca, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=LOC, ST=ST, C=US]
SerialNumber: [    1000]
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

#6: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
NetscapeCertType [
   SSL server
]

#7: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 8F 68 EC C9 3F 62 27 34   47 D4 AB FE 61 31 67 57  .h..?b'4G...a1gW
0010: DF 4A B8 7C                                        .J..
]
]
```

jarsigner -verify output of this recent jar file **without problem**:
jarsigner -verify -verbose -keystore custom2.jks -certs custom.jar testalias

```
s k      151 Wed Oct 12 14:34:38 EDT 2016 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

      X.509, CN=myserver, OU=CA, O=CA, L=CA, ST=CA, C=CA (testalias)
      [certificate is valid from 10/12/16 2:33 PM to 10/12/17 2:33 PM]
      [ExtendedKeyUsage, NetscapeCertType extension does not support code signing]

         313 Wed Oct 12 14:34:38 EDT 2016 META-INF/TESTALIA.SF
        1933 Wed Oct 12 14:34:38 EDT 2016 META-INF/TESTALIA.RSA
           0 Wed Oct 12 14:34:38 EDT 2016 META-INF/
smk     1506 Wed Oct 12 14:34:38 EDT 2016 testabc.jks

      X.509, CN=myserver, OU=CA, O=CA, L=CA, ST=CA, C=CA (testalias)
      [certificate is valid from 10/12/16 2:33 PM to 10/12/17 2:33 PM]
      [ExtendedKeyUsage, NetscapeCertType extension does not support code signing]


  s = signature was verified 
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope
  X = not signed by specified alias(es)

jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate's ExtendedKeyUsage extension doesn't allow code signing.
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate's NetscapeCertType extension doesn't allow code signing.
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2017-10-12) or after any future revocation date.
```

Comment: There is no code_sign extension in X.509; there is a codeSigning OID used in the value of the ExtendedKeyUsage extension, which your exception mentions. CSR generated by `keytool` doesn't request any EKU; `openssl req` can be configured to, but stock OpenSSL (upstream) does not do so, I don't see why any packager would change this, and presumably you didn't change it without saying so in your Q. And in any case the CA can ignore any requested extension and should do so if it is wrong. ...

Comment: ... I constructed test certs with good and bad EKU, and `jarsigner` from Oracle jdk8u05 does warn (but NOT fail) at signing time if EKU is bad, which I assume didn't happen for you or you would have said so. I would look at each signing cert, and to be thorough their chains as well, in the keystores you use to sign, and see exactly what they have for EKU and KU; conveniently `keytool -list -v -alias whatever` displays all attributes and extensions for the full chain.

Comment: I understand and agree with your points re: EKU and codeSigning. I'm not sure what you mean about a good/bad EKU. But jarsigner did warn me while jarsigning it with both: 1. openssl created certs; and 2. the keystore created certs. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce getting things to work with the certificates used by openssl. I know I definitely wasn't imagining things since I was doing it multiple times across different/new docker containers with different certs. I had also used the keystore -list -v output which didn't help me. Since I can't reproduce, ideas on what to do with the question?

Comment: (1) 'good and bad EKU' means (certs containing) EKU with the codeSIgning OID and jarsigner is happy versus EKU with a different OID and jarsigner warns `The signer certificate's ExtendedKeyUsage extension doesn't allow code signing.` (1) If jarsigner warned **about EKU** then I expect the resulting jar to fail in jnlp (although I couldn't easily test) (2) `-list -v` shows among other things the extensions in your certs -- do they have the right EKU (codeSigning), the wrong EKU (something else), or no EKU?